# AVPlayer won't play HLS stream URL with special characters

Tags: ios, avplayer, http-live-streaming

I want to play a streaming video on iOS. Users upload the video with special characters in the filename (.mp4). It works well when AVPlayer plays it with the encoded URL (https://.../%F0%9F%98%82.mp4). But if I use AWS MediaConvert to convert it to M3U8 (https://.../%F0%9F%98%82.m3u8), AVPlayer plays it with the error:

> https://.../%F0%9F%98%82_hls_qvbr_7_2000k_00001.ts CoreMediaErrorDomain -12938 - HTTP 404: File Not Found.

I checked the content of M3U8, names look correct:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-INDEPENDENT-SEGMENTS
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=232969,AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=231047,CODECS="avc1.77.30,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=640x480,FRAME-RATE=30.000
_hls_qvbr_9_6000k.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=205897,AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=204707,CODECS="avc1.77.30,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=640x480,FRAME-RATE=30.000
_hls_qvbr_7_2000k.m3u8
```

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXTINF:10,
_hls_qvbr_7_2000k_00001.ts
#EXTINF:10,
_hls_qvbr_7_2000k_00002.ts
...
```

I tried the same URL with the VLC player, it can play. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I am not completely sure of your case, but from what you have provided I can only assume that has something to do with encoding the url. Could you share how you are passing the link to the AVPlayer? I also had something with the AWS and image downloading recently, could probably help you.

Comment: i have the same problem, the main HLS url is encoded, but the nested ones aren't and Safari dont like it