# HLS video with special characteres in URL doesn't play on iOS Safari (Flutter)

Tags: ios, flutter, stream, http-live-streaming

I'm working on a video stream type of APP in Flutter. I implemented the video streaming with `better_player` and the video itself is being hosted on AWS.

Everything working fine until I tried testing on an iOS device and it broke. I pinpointed the problem as being in the video's URL, since `better_player` wasn't being able to find the video. All the videos that didn't load had special characteres in their URL (Ç, Ã, Â, Á, À), which are very commom in portuguese, then the URL is encoded as an URI, but the `m3u8` file still references the non-encoded `.ts` URLs and iOS seem to not parse these automatically.

[image: example1]

As you can see the highlighted words all have a `ú` character, and it just breaks everything, thus making iOS/Safari not being able to retrieve the video.

Does anyone have any insight about it?
Can I solve it inside Flutter or do I have to change all my URLs (I would prefer not doing it)?

Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75091544/19986141), but it doesn't have any answers so I thought of asking again.

I tried encoding the stream URL into a URI friendly format, iOS still can't load it.

Comment: Have you tried percentencoding?

Comment: Yes, the original HLS file path is encoded, but inside it has references to .ts files with no encoding. Some browsers automatically encode it but not Safari. I will just go the long way and rename everything.

Comment: Well then this seems to be an issue on the server, does it? Or what creates these files?

Comment: Yeah it is. I just wanted to know if there's a way to circumvent it